# How to convert multiple join associated with aggregate function Linq to sql C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I want to write the following query using Linq to sql ? 
I tried to do it , but I'm a beginner in Linq and I got lost in it , Any Help please or any tips for articles that can help to figure this out ??

```
select (s.fname + '' + s.lname ) as doctor_name  , appointment_id , [date/time] , price , type ,                                                                                                                                           
patient_id
from staff s
,
(select  appointment_id,[date/time] , price , apptype.type , patient_id , [doctor-id] from     

AppointmentType apptype ,
(  select * 
from Appointments app
where app.appointment_id = 
(
    select Max(appointment_id) as lastApp
    from Appointments app1
    where app1.patient_id = app.patient_id and app.patient_id=10
) 
) as rr
where apptype.id = rr.type
) as dd
where dd.[doctor-id] = s.id
```

Any Tips Please , Thanks Any Way :)

Comment: Could you show us the code you've written so far? At the very least we'd know the names and properties of your entities then..

Answer (score 0):

```
                using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
                {
                      var x = from apptype in db.AppointmentTypes
                                    from rr in (
                                        (from app in db.Appointments
                                           where
                                           app.appointment_id == 
                                            (from app1 in db.Appointments
                                              where
                                              app1.patient_id == app.patient_id &&
                                              app.patient_id == patient.Patient_id
                                            select new {
                                              app1.appointment_id
                                            }).Max(p => p.appointment_id)
                                        select new {
                                          app
                                        }))
                                 where
                                 apptype.id == rr.app.type
                                    select new {
                                        apptype.id,
                                   //   apptype.appointment_id,
                                    ///// take ***  Column1 =  rr.app.date_time ,
                                      apptype.price,
                                      apptype.type,
                                      rr.app.patient_id      //   apptype.patient_id,
                                     // Column2 = (apptype.doctor - apptype.id)
                                    };
```